# Limit: Find a number k

Tags: limits, functions

A positive number $\varepsilon$ and the limit $L$ of a function $f$ at a point $a$ are given. Find a number $k$ such that $|f(x)-L|<\varepsilon$ if $0<|x-a| < k$.

How to solve these question.
$$\lim_{x\to9}\sqrt x=3;\varepsilon=0.001$$
$$\lim_{x\to5}\frac1x=\frac15; \varepsilon= 0.05$$

Comment: I think there is a problem in the statement. k is not defined.

Comment: I updated it. There is a symbol which I replace with k.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT**

You have to follow the definition of finite limit $L$ and find for each example a number k such that:

$\forall x_0 \quad0<|x_0-a| < k$

$|f(x_0)-L|<\varepsilon$

For the first:

$$\lim_{x\to9}\sqrt x=3;\varepsilon=0.001$$

note that:

$$\quad0<|x-9| < k \iff 9-k<x < 9+k $$

$$|\sqrt x-3|<\varepsilon \iff 3-\varepsilon <\sqrt x < 3+\varepsilon \iff (3-\varepsilon)^2 < x < (3+\varepsilon)^2 $$

**NOTE** in the previous equality you can square because alla quantities are positive

thus

$$(3-\varepsilon)^2 < 9-k< x <9+k <(3+\varepsilon)^2 $$

that is

$$\begin{cases}
k<9-(3-\varepsilon)^2=9-9+6\varepsilon - \varepsilon^2=6\varepsilon - \varepsilon^2 \\
k<(3+\varepsilon)^2-9=9+6\varepsilon + \varepsilon^2-9=6\varepsilon + \varepsilon^2 \end{cases}$$

$$\iff k<6\varepsilon - \varepsilon^2 \\$$

Comment: I am stuck here. I don't know what do next after this. |sqrt(x) - 3 | < 0.001 if 0 < |x - 9| < k

Comment: If the alebric solution is not requated, let's choose a small k and verify the inequality with calculator, if it doesn't work reduce k by k/10 and try again! If the alebric solution is requated, you need to do a bit of work!

Comment: I solve bunch of question like this. But I am not getting this problem. This algebric expressions is confusing me. Can you give a complete solution.

Comment: The question ask find a number, thus I think that you could solve by calculation without express a formula.

Comment: sorry. I mean I need a solution.

Comment: I've just update a complete solution for the first case.

Answer (score 0):

**ANOTHER HINT**

If I write this:

$$|\sqrt{x} - 3| = \frac{|\sqrt{x} - 3||\sqrt{x} + 3|}{|\sqrt{x} + 3|} = \frac{|x-9|}{|\sqrt{x} + 3|}$$

Does it help?

Note that ${|\sqrt{x} + 3|}$ is close to $6$ for $x$ close to $9$.

EDIT: I actually like gimusis answer better, but for completeness: I was thinking:

Since you want $|\sqrt x - 3| < \epsilon$, you want $6 -\epsilon <\sqrt x + 3 < 6 +\epsilon$, and since $\sqrt x + 3$ is positive for $x$ around $9$, we have

$$\frac {1} {|\sqrt x + 3|} = \frac {1} {\sqrt x + 3} < \frac {1}{6-\epsilon} $$ And now it's clear what $k$ we pick, namely any $k < \epsilon(6-\epsilon)$

Hope it helps

Comment: I am working on it.

Comment: Added full solution to the first one. Is everything clear?

Comment: That's lot clear  now. :)